# How to enable follow Redirect in Nutch-1.0

Tags: nutch

I am using Nutch-1.0 and I am getting this log entry
2009-11-12 22:13:11,093 INFO  httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - Redirect requested but followRedirects is disabled.
How to enable Follow Redirect.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

I have used Nutch-1.0.Please check the Nutch-1.0 server-site.xml file and set all property as defaut of Nutch-1.0.

[Here is the link for reference](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/release-0.8/CHANGES.txt), I think this works.